# Correct usage of js.ThisFunction0

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js, w2ui

I am trying to get scala.js working in conjunction with the w2ui jQuery library. However, when I define my reset action in a form, the behaviour is not as I would have expected.

In order to handle my reset action. I define something like the following in my scalajs code:

```
...
 actions = js.Dynamic.literal(
  reset = { form: W2Form =>
   form.clear()
  }: js.Function1[W2Form, Any],
...
```

However this causes an error when I click the reset button:

> TypeError: this.refresh is not a function
>   this.refresh();
>   ^

On examining the generated javascript code I can see why this error occurs:

```
"actions": {
  "reset": (function(f) {
    return (function() {
      return f.apply__O__O(this)
    })
  })(new $c_sjsr_AnonFunction1().init___sjs_js_Function1((function(form$2) {
    return (0, form$2["clear"])()
  }))),
```

This can be rectified changing the last line by hand to:

```
  return (form$2["clear"])()
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm.  I don't know w2ui, and the documentation isn't as well-organized as I might wish.  Can you point to the docs for actions and reset, so I can understand what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `js.ThisFunction0` is perfectly fine. Your issue comes from your call to `clear`. I suspect you defined `clear` like this in `W2Form`:

```
@js.native
class W2Form(...) extends js.Object {
  val clear: js.Function0[Unit] = js.native // or var or def
  ...
}
```

That would cause `form.clear()` to first select the field `clear` from `form`, then calling the retrieved function independently from `form`. If you want `clear` to be called as a *method* of `form`, you need to declare it as a method:

```
def clear(): Unit = js.native
```